# Парсер товаров из XML файла

Tags: php, xml

Есть файл yml интернет магазина, можно ли как нибудь превратить его в массив и записать все данный в БД?

вот пример:

```
<steambuy.response>
<response>
<status>success</status>
<error/>
<data>
<goods>
<id_good>2319107</id_good>
<name>Far Cry 5</name>
<available>1</available>
<price>
<rub>799</rub>
</price>
</goods>
<goods>
<id_good>2319108</id_good>
<name>Far Cry 5 - Deluxe Edition</name>
<available>0</available>
<price/>
</goods>
<goods>
<id_good>2319109</id_good>
<name>Far Cry 5 - Gold Edition</name>
<available>0</available>
<price/>
</goods>
<goods>
<id_good>2451185</id_good>
<name>Far Cry 5 - Season Pass</name>
<available>0</available>
<price/>
</goods>
</data>
</response>
</steambuy.response>
```

Пробую делать так, не выводит ничего. Хотя вроде все логично)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://steammachine.ru/api/search/?q=far%20cry%205&v=1&format=xml');
$game = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

/* Для каждого узла <character>, мы отдельно выведем имя <name>. */
foreach ($game->steambuy.response->response->data->goods as $goods) {
   echo $goods->name, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: [Легко и просто](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php)! И далее собрать в массив и делать что душе угодно

Comment: Попробовал как в примере (обновил вопрос) что-то я упустил?

Comment: @РоманРоманюк, Посмотрите мой ответ. Ваша ошибка была в том, что вы пытались второй раз инициализировать объект. Функция `simplexml_load_file` уже возвращает объект,  с которым можно дальше работать

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://steammachine.ru/api/search/q=far%20cry%205&v=1&format=xml');
foreach($xml->response->data->goods as $good){
   echo $good->name . PHP_EOL;
}
```